# Facebook web error: The application may not be valid

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm getting an odd error with a Facebook web app, via the console:

> There was a problem getting data for the application you requested.
>   The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch.
>   Please try again later. - oauth:1

Switching in or out of sandbox mode doesn't seem to help. I'm hosing on Heroku. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Does this happen with every call?

Comment: Yeah, where are you seeing that error and what are you doing when you see it?

Comment: Yep - happens on every time I load the app. Just appears in the JS console as soon as the DOM/page finishes loading.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460943/application-error-while-loading-the-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me when I was using the pageId instead of the appId...

```
(function(d, s, id, appId) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + appId; //<--passing config value here
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk', config.appId)); //<--I added the extra param here b/c I am loading the config via a xhr.
```